# Pytorch gather function to get current Q values for Deep Q

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to compute the current Q for deep Q learning but am running into this error:

```
RuntimeError: invalid argument 4: Index tensor must have same dimensions as input tensor at C:/w/1/s/windows/pytorch/aten/src\THC/generic/THCTensorScatterGather.cu:16
```

The code triggering this error is this:

`curr_Q = self.model.forward(states).gather(1, actions.unsqueeze(1))`

The shape of `self.model.forward(states)` is [32, 640, 10], and the shape of actions is [32].

The rest of the code in this function is here:

```
 def compute_loss(self, batch):
    states, actions, rewards, next_states, dones = batch
    states = torch.FloatTensor(states).to(self.device)
    actions = torch.LongTensor(actions).to(self.device)
    rewards = torch.FloatTensor(rewards).to(self.device)
    next_states = torch.FloatTensor(next_states).to(self.device)
    dones = torch.FloatTensor(dones)

    curr_Q = self.model.forward(states).gather(1, actions.unsqueeze(1))
    curr_Q = curr_Q.squeeze(1)
    next_Q = self.model.forward(next_states)
    max_next_Q = torch.max(next_Q, 1)[0]
    expected_Q = rewards.squeeze(1) + self.gamma * max_next_Q

    loss = self.MSE_loss(curr_Q, expected_Q)
    return loss
```

Comment: see if the output dimension from self.model.forward(states) matches the dimension of the action.unsqueeze(1)